# cakephp 3: find('list') isn't returning records on specific query

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I'm having issue with find('list') which is not returning rows on a specific values. But, when I'm executing the same query in SQLYog GUI it is actually returning rows.

Screenshot of cakePHP Debug kit SQL Log Query:
[image]

Screenshot of records when I execute this query in SQLYog GUI:
[image]

See below code which I'm using in a controller:

```
$proposal_part_length = number_format($filterForm['proposal_part_length'], 4, '.', '');
$proposal_part_width = number_format($filterForm['proposal_part_width'], 4, '.', '');

$this->loadModel('ProposalParts');
$parts = array();

$parts = $this->ProposalParts
    ->find('list', [
        'keyField' => 'id',
        'valueField' => 'proposal_id'
    ])
    ->where(['ProposalParts.length' => $proposal_part_length, 'ProposalParts.width' => $proposal_part_width])
    ->distinct(['ProposalParts.proposal_id'])
    ->toArray();
```

Both fields in where clause datatypes are "float(11,4)". I've tried removing "number_format" function but still no records found with that QUERY but system is showing up records, if I change "length" and "width" values, like: "5", "1" or "5.0000", "1.0000".

Does anyone have suggestion what's wrong with this?

If you've any questions let me know.

Comment: Enable SQL logging and examine the exact query that's being executed to see how it differs from your manual one.

Comment: CakePHP3 Debug kit SQL Log Query returns 0 whereas on SQLYug I'm getting 3 records using same exact query which cakePHP3 provided in SQL Log.

I'm not sure what SQL logging will help me with that if I'll enable SQL logging. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: There are only two possibilities to explain this. Either you're accidentally connecting to a different database in your application than in your manual test, or the SQL query that's being executed is different. Assuming it's not the former, then it must be the latter, and carefully examining (or copy-and-pasting) the exact query that Cake is executing should be helpful in nailing this down.

Comment: I'm not connecting to a different database in my application than in manual test, nor the SQL query that's being executed is different. So your assumption is wrong.

Comment: I can think of no other reason why you would get some results one way and none the other. Sorry!

Comment: Unfortunately you can't 100% rely on CakePHP to show you the _exact_ query when bound parameters are involved, as the final query with the bound parameters inserted is being composed by PHP's PDO library, not by CakePHP. So it can only emulate what the query might look like, and currently it doesn't take the PDO parameter types into account. So to see the exact query you need to log it at your database server, not at PHP level! Floats for example are usually being bound as strings, as PDO doesn't have a float type.